# AxWindowsMediaPlayer skip back and forth frame by frame

Tags: winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a WMV file playing in an `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` object. I have two buttons that are enabled when the video is paused. One should skip backwards one frame, and the other should skip forwards one frame.

The problem is, if I just add 1/24ths of a second (the length of a typical frame) to `Ctlcontrols.currentPosition` while the video is paused, the control doesn't update.

So I tried playing it and pausing it directly after, but that makes it play for about a second before pausing it.

How should I go about doing this? Is it even possible with `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`? If not, what other video player could I use?

**EDIT**

Oh, another idea... is there a way to make the screen update while paused after setting `currentPosition`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API to use is IWMPControls2' step function.

Eg:  `((IWMPControls2)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols).step(1);`